# how to enable a device to follow you

Tags: tracking-devices

I am trying to find out what IoT devices I shall use to enable a device(say a small toy car) to have an ability to follow a particular person.

So far what I have found:

1. QR Code, print out the QR code and stick to yourself and let the car to track the QR code. Con: I don't expect my friends or family to print out an QR code and stick to themselves.... which looks funny, impractical
2. UWB.
   I noticed this technology recently. It enables cm-level positioning, but super expensive.

I am looking for an affordable solution.

Or use what I have:

1. Lidar
2. OpenCV AI Camera Oak 1 and Oak D
3. Raspberry Pi 4
4. An Android mobile Phone which has Wifi and Bluetooth
5. A GPS IoT Module

Not sure whether is it possible to use what I already have to enable the person following capability.

So my questions are:

```
are there any affordable IoT devices to enable tracking a particular person within short distance(e.g. short than 10 meters)

Is it possible to use existing devices which I have to do the person tacking?
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using their phones Bluetooth signal? They pair it like a headset and it just follows that. You could just use a headset that tells you when you are out of range so it always stays in range.

Comment: hi Vick, that's what 1st flashed in my mind~! But I then realized that BLE only knows "are you within its range", it does not know "what is your exactly position related to its position", in other words, it does know how to find whether you are at its left side or right side and how long is the distance between you and itself.